# Cannot add a glassfish server in eclipse!

Tags: eclipse

After many efforts, i did installing of java_ee on my system.
I'm using eclipse Galileo. After i try to add a new server, I choose the location for glassfish, click next and it gives me:

```
home/banco/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1 is not writable
```

Since the glassfish is situated in Home folder, i can't understand the reason for this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is placed in your home directory, it doesn't give you automaticly write permission to files.

Have you checked the folder permissions with ls -l ?

```
ls -l home/banco/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1
```

Sometimes I decompress archives as the wrong user in my home directory and have similiar errors...

Comment: I think you unpacked glassfish as root and started eclipse as a normal user.

See http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/filepermissions.html

You should spend also some time to check some basic OS documentation like http://tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/